# ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'eoip_if'. See ovs-vswitchd log for details

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, bridge, network-namespaces

I have a namespace ns1, inside this i run a eoip script which create a interface eoip_if. I also have a ovs-bridge br0 which is in default namespace. When i try adding the 'eoip_if' interface as a port to the bridge br0 its giving me below error:

**ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'eoip_if'.  See ovs-vswitchd log for details.**

```
    Bridge br0
        Port br0
            Interface br-wan
                type: internal
        Port int
            Interface int
                type: internal
        Port eoip_if
            Interface eoip_if
                error: "could not open network device eoip_if(No such device)"
        Port eth1
            Interface eth1
    ovs_version: "2.5.5"
```

**ip a** inside ns1:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eoip_if: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8800 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:7d:e3:29:7e:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::4c7d:e3ff:fe29:7e1b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```